# Startup failure with meteor-socket-io

Tags: javascript, sockets, meteor, socket.io

I wanted to set up a meteor app with socket.io and used the example from https://github.com/Akryum/meteor-socket-io and installed everything in this way. When I wanted to start meteor than, I recieve the error message:

At startup TypeError: socket_io.server is not a function

I tried to import socket_io in different ways, but I'm a absolute newbie to meteor (first application...) and the solution might be total obvious

As given from the github-project I tried

```
// Meteor Socket from https://github.com/Akryum/meteor-socket-io
import http from 'http';
import socket_io from 'socket.io';

const PORT = 8080;

Meteor.startup(() => {

  // Server
  const server = http.createServer();
  const io = socket_io(server);

...
```

The resulting error message is:

```
W20190912-17:07:15.698(2)? (STDERR) /home/fips/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.1.ani1yi.p0f9s++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20190912-17:07:15.698(2)? (STDERR)                                             throw(ex);
W20190912-17:07:15.698(2)? (STDERR)                                             ^
W20190912-17:07:15.699(2)? (STDERR) 
W20190912-17:07:15.699(2)? (STDERR) TypeError: socket_io.server is not a function
W20190912-17:07:15.699(2)? (STDERR)     at Meteor.startup (server/main.js:15:24)
W20190912-17:07:15.699(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.time ([...removed...]/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:309:28)
W20190912-17:07:15.699(2)? (STDERR)     at [...removed...]/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:435:13
W20190912-17:07:15.699(2)? (STDERR)     at [...removed...]/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:480:5
W20190912-17:07:15.700(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.run [...removed...]/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
W20190912-17:07:15.700(2)? (STDERR)     at [...removed...]/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:478:11
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

I think(!) I understand why it is not a function but I fail to have an idea how to call the socket_io it elsewise.

Comment: Is there a reason you're creating a new socket instead of using the built in socket?

Comment: Also I'm confused why the error says `socket_io.server` with a dot, while your code snippet has `socket_io(server)`. Is there a typo?

Comment: This means that socket.io is undefined, suggesting that the import didn't work. Have you tried requiring it with something like `require('socket.io')`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, the require('socket.io') din't work not it gave an error (except the one above) - so I switched to a different solution with executing the socket-thing only server-side. Which might be a better idea anyway.